# Retrofit POST response conversion fails without a trace

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson, retrofit2

I'm building an app for a company using MVVM & clean architecture so I've created 3 modules, the app module (presentation layer), the data module (data layer) & the domain module (domain/interactors layer). Now, in my data module, I'm using Retrofit and Gson to automatically convert the JSON I'm receiving from a login POST request to my kotlin data class named NetUserSession that you see below. The problem I'm having is that the logging interceptor prints the response with the data in it normally but the `response.body()` returns an empty NetUserSession object with null values which makes me think that the automatic conversion isn't happening for some reason. Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

KoinModules:

```
val domainModule = module {
            single<LoginRepository> {LoginRepositoryImpl(get())}
            single { LoginUseCase(get()) }
        }
        val presentationModule = module {
            viewModel { LoginViewModel(get(),get()) }
        }
        val dataModule = module {
            single { ApiServiceImpl().getApiService() }
            single { LoginRepositoryImpl(get()) }
        }
}
```

Api interface & retrofit:

```
interface ApiService {
    @POST("Login")
    fun getLoginResult(@Body netUser: NetUser) : Call<NetUserSession>

    @GET("Books")
    fun getBooks(@Header("Authorization") token:String) : Call<List<NetBook>>
}

class ApiServiceImpl {
    fun getApiService(): ApiService {
        val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
        //TODO:SP Remove the interceptor code when done debugging
        val client: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(logging)
            .build()

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build()
        // tell retrofit to implement the interface of our api
        return retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
    }
}
```

NetUserSession:

```
data class NetUserSession(
    @SerializedName("expires_in")
    val expires_in: Int,
    @SerializedName("token_type")
    val token_type: String,
    @SerializedName("refresh_token")
    val refresh_token: String,
    @SerializedName("access_token")
    val access_token: String
) {
    fun toUserSession(): UserSession = UserSession(
        expiresIn = expires_in,
        tokenType = token_type,
        refreshToken = refresh_token,
        accessToken = access_token
    )
}
```

UserSession in domain:

```
data class UserSession(
    val expiresIn:Int,
    val tokenType:String,
    val refreshToken:String,
    val accessToken:String
)
```

LoginRepositoryImpl where the error occurs:

```
class LoginRepositoryImpl(private val apiService: ApiService) : LoginRepository {

    override suspend fun login(username:String,password:String): UserSession? = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
        val response = apiService.getLoginResult(NetUser(username,password)).awaitResponse()
        println("THE RESPONSE WAS : ${response.body()}")
        return@withContext if(response.isSuccessful) response.body()?.toUserSession() else null
    }
}
```

LoggingInterceptor result after the 200-OK:

```
{"expires_in":3600,"token_type":"Bearer","refresh_token":"T1amGR21.IdKM.5ecbf91162691e15913582bf2662e0","access_token":"T1amGT21.Idup.298885bf38e99053dca3434eb59c6aa"}
```

Response.body() print result:

```
THE RESPONSE WAS : NetUserSession(expires_in=0, token_type=null, refresh_token=null, access_token=null)
```

Any ideas what I'm failing to see here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After busting my head for hours, the solution was to simply change the model class's members from `val` to `var` like so :

```
data class NetUserSession(
    @SerializedName("expires_in")
    var expires_in: Int = 0,
    @SerializedName("token_type")
    var token_type: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("refresh_token")
    var refresh_token: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("access_token")
    var access_token: String? = null
) {
    fun toUserSession(): UserSession = UserSession(
        expiresIn = expires_in,
        tokenType = token_type!!,
        refreshToken = refresh_token!!,
        accessToken = access_token!!
    )
}
```